# Centering a paragraph with <div> without background spreading out

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website, and I want to have on the About page of it, I want the background of the paragraph to be crimson in a way that it looks likes it's floating. Right now, I'm trying to get it so that when I style it, it doesn't stretches out to the ends of the page. I want it to be more about 25% way.

This is my coding right now

```
<div>
          <iframe src="Main page.html" width="1350" height="200" style="border:none;"></iframe>
          </div>
    <!---About Page-->
    <div class="-paragraph">
      <p class="paragraph">text here</p>
  </div>
```

for HTML

```
body {
  background-color:#000000;
}

.-paragraph {
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  color:white;
}

.paragraph {
  background-color:#DC143C;
}
```

and my CSS

I already asked this question before and it was seen as a duplicate question, but I found no answers I understood, and I didn't get any answers that worked how I needed.

The background color I want to be black, and then I want a bit of a floating box around the text with the crimson color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
.paragraph {
  background-color:#DC143C;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```